# How do I add Stockfish.js to my react (+ typescript) application?

Tags: reactjs, webassembly, react-tsx

I'm trying to build a chess application where you can play vs stockfish. I tried implementing stockfish with `stockfish.js` ([github link](https://github.com/nmrugg/stockfish.js)) but I couldn't get it to work. I tried the following approaches:

1. Add stockfish to public folder and enable it in my index.html (With and without %PUBLIC_URL% and type):
   [image: img1]

When i tried using `(window as any).STOCKFISH()` it still did not work.

2. Add stockfish to public folder and use a webworker:

[image]

This got the following error:
*abort(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f*
I found out that 3c 21 44 4f means <!DO so that it probably can't find it.

3. Simply require it (`var stockfish = require("stockfish")`)

This didn't work neither.

I'm doing something wrong and it would be great if someone could help me with implementing this. Thanks in advance